# Eliminate part of a circle outside certain limits in python matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote this code for plot an image:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(len(pos_eje_x)):
    ax.bar3d(pos_eje_x[i],pos_eje_y[i],z_altura[i], dx[i], dy[i], altura[i], alpha=1, color='w', linewidth=2)

ax.scatter(200, 500, 500, color='r', marker='^', s=150)

circle_1 = Circle((200, 500), 500*np.tan(np.deg2rad(60 / 2)), fill=False, clip_on=False)
ax.add_patch(circle_1)
art3d.pathpatch_2d_to_3d(circle_1, z=25, zdir="z")

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1000)
ax.set_xlim3d(0, L)
ax.set_ylim3d(0, L)
ax.set_xlim(0, L)
ax.set_ylim(0, L)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1000)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.title('Map 3D')
ax.view_init(elev=30., azim=-35)
```

Here is my output:

[image: Plot 3d]

How can I remove the rest of the circle that goes out of bounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw a circle manually an than cut out the piece that is not within the limits. You have to pay attention though, that start and end of your pizza slice are at the correct position otherwise an additional unwanted connection is drawn.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d as art3d  # noqa: F401 unused import

def get_circle(x, r, n=360):
    q = np.linspace(start=-np.pi, stop=np.pi, num=n)

    c = np.empty((n, len(x)))
    c[:, 0] = np.cos(q)*r + x[0]
    c[:, 1] = np.sin(q)*r + x[1]
    if len(x) == 3:
        c[:, 2] = x[2]

    return c

def cut_circle(c, limits):
    idx_keep_x = np.logical_and(limits[0, 0] < c[:, 0], c[:, 0] < limits[0, 1])
    idx_keep_y = np.logical_and(limits[1, 0] < c[:, 1], c[:, 1] < limits[1, 1])
    idx_keep = np.logical_and(idx_keep_x, idx_keep_y)

    c2 = c[idx_keep, :]

    c2_help = np.concatenate([c2, c2[:1, :]])
    i_jump = np.argmax(np.linalg.norm(np.diff(c2_help[:, :2], axis=0), axis=-1))

    c3 = np.roll(c2, -(i_jump+1), axis=0)

    return c2, c3


limits = np.array([[20, 50],
                   [30, 60],
                   [0, 20]])

c1 = get_circle(x=[45, 55, 5], r=10)
c2, c3 = cut_circle(c=c1, limits=limits)

c2[:,  2] += 5
c3[:, 2] += 10


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

ax.set_xlim(limits[0])
ax.set_ylim(limits[1])
ax.set_zlim(limits[2])

ax.plot(*c1.T)
ax.plot(*c2.T)
ax.plot(*c3.T)
```

[image]

Comment: Replace "c" with "c1" in the following lines of code:idx_keep_x = np.logical_and(limits[0, 0] < c1[:, 0], c1[:, 0] < limits[0, 1])
    idx_keep_y = np.logical_and(limits[1, 0] < c1[:, 1], c1[:, 1] < limits[1, 1])